# Condition Checking in a FOR loop when checking for an array element

Tags: c, for-loop

Could you please justify the output of the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
     int i,A[]={0,5};

     for(i=0; i<2 && (A[i]==5) ;i++)
         printf("%d",i);
}
```

According to me, the output should be 1.
But on running the code, I don't get any output.
Could you please explain what is happening?
I am new to programming and would prefer a non-complex answer.

Comment: The condition for the loop `i<2 && (A[i]==5)`  is never true so the loop is never entered.

Answer (score 2):

Because the expression `A[i]==5` is *false* when `i` is `0`. True and false is false, so the loop never runs.